# RELATION "customers " does not exist but in fact exits

Tags: node.js, postgresql

im trying to put together a simple website, but when trying to insert to my Heroku database it says my relation (table) does not exist but in fact exists!!..I connect through database_url provided by Heroku and when I connect through my command line and insert new rows, they get added and I can see their table and data but when I try to insert the data everytime I hit summit in the form, the error pops up like there were no table with that name..

```
const express = require('express');
app =  express();
require('dotenv').config()
var sslRedirect  = require("heroku-ssl-redirect").default;
var compression = require('compression');
const { Client } = require('pg');
const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
})

//MIDDLEWARE
app.set("port",process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(sslRedirect());
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        extended:false
    })
);
app.use
const errorController  = require('./controllers/errorController');
//const middleware = require('./controllers/middleware')

//ROUTES

app.get('/',(req,res,next) => {
    res.render('test')
});
app.post('/thanks', async (req, res) => {
    
    data = {
            name : req.body.name,
            email : req.body.email,
            service: req.body.service,
            message: req.body.message};
    
    const text ='INSERT INTO customers(name,email,service,message) VALUES($1, 2$, 3$, 4$)   RETURNING *;'
const values =  [data.name, data.email, data.service,   data.message];
    
    client.connect()
      try {
        const res = await client.query(`INSERT INTO customers (name,email,service,message) VALUES(${data.name},${data.email},${data.service},${data.message}) RETURNING *;`);
        console.log(res.row[1])
        client.end()
    
      }catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
        client.end()
      }
      res.render('thanks')
})
app.get('/contact',(req,res) => {
        res.render('contact')
})

app.get("/services" , (req,res) => {
           res.render('services')
})

app.get("/about" , (req,res) => {
        res.render("about")
})

app.get('/maysspabeauty.com/contact/*' , (req , res) => {
       res.render('contact')
})


app.use(errorController.pageNotFoundError);
app.use(errorController.internalServerError)
app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log(`server running at http://localhost:${app.get("port")}`);
});
```

here is screenshot of the error[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS0s3.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not a link to a painting of it.

Comment: Are you sure that your code is connecting to the correct (same) database as you do?

Comment: yes im connected, through a database_url provided by Heroku and when and I use Heroku config in command line , i can verify the url is the same as when I access the data base through their site and see the config vars, thanks for answering

Comment: In what schema did you create `customers`? Is it on the `search_path` for the client connection?

Comment: the schema I used is the one Postgres create for you! the public schema and, I believe my search_path would be my database_url? that they provided me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this.... seems my problem was just that i was using heroku hobby-dynos and they are NOT  meant to be used in production....after i upgraded the dynos, it just throw me this error (no pg_hba.conf entry for host) which i fixed just using ssl"{
ssl:
rejectUnauthorized:false
};